# Why is my R density plot a bell curve when all datapoints are 0?

Tags: r

When I graph a density plot in R, and all the numbers are slightly greater than 0, I get essentially a vertical line at x = 0.  But when all the numbers are exactly equal to 0, I get some sort of bell curve.  Why is that?  It seems counterintuitive.

The command I used to plot the curves was

```
for (i in 0:60) {
    cur_data = subset(data, time == i)
    p <- ggplot(cur_data, aes(x=error)) +
    geom_density() +
    theme_bw() +
    xlab(paste("Error distribution (minute ", i, ")", sep="")) +
    xlim(0, 1)
    ggsave(...)
}
```

At i = 60, cur_data should be entirely populated by the values 0.0.

[image: Density plot, entries slightly greater than 0]

[image: Density plot, entries all 0]

Comment: What are the data? And what is your plotting command?

Comment: Try: `plot(density(rnorm(1000,0,0.001)),xlim=c(0,1))` and 
`plot(density(rnorm(1000,0,0.00)),xlim=c(0,1))`

Comment: Added the plotting command.

Comment: You seems to have some wiggle in the density around .125 in the top plot. Anyway, this has more to do with how density curves are estimated rather than any specific programming question. If that's the case, your question better belongs on [stats.se] where discussions of statistical methods are on-topic.